# Network structure for multiple ISP failover

Tags: firewall, exchange, load-balancing, router, failover

I want to create a corporate data center that will use 3 ISPs. I want to use load balancing and/or fail over with 2 of the 3 ISP because they will be used for MS Exchange servers and web servers. The remaining ISP service will be for regular internet services. I am trying to determine the best network mapping/setup for such services.

All local computers and sub networks will be using Windows active directory and all of the web servers and exchange servers will belong to the AD domain.

In my head i'm visualizing this setup:

ISP 1,2 & 3 --> Cisco 2941 or 2911 router --> FW --> SWITCH --> Servers & Workstations

Ideally, I want the firewall to be between the ISP and the router. I'd rather have packets filtered out before getting into the LAN. How can I do this with proper fail over and high availability?

I may have this kind of setup for a total of 3 sites.

Comment: I suggest using a basic Link balancer or a firewall that can accommodate multiple ISPs. Can you describe the firewall options you have and why you need _three_ ISPs?

Comment: have a look at gslb?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a link balancer as a gateway. There are many types and a common open source solution would be to use [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org) with x86 hardware - pfSense even sell appliances that run this. Cisco iOS doesn't have good multiWAN capability in low end devices.